# create js file/code for other user to embed to use on their sites

Tags: php

I am creating a newsletter on my site, and after its completion I need to give a user a code to embed on their sites so they can directly show that pages on their sites. For this I am creating the HTML file for the main newsletter pages, now the main problem for me is - how to create a JS script for it and give the code for embedding it to thier site.

Please give me some suggestions here

Comment: @cwallenpoole : Thanks for your suggestion.I think using iframe will be the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

You just echo the required code such that it will be displayed in a textbox in the site. Customize the embed code as required using php.

Comment: Here I need to give user the code to embed to their site. At the last of the newsletter completion I need to give one button for them that will give the JS code for them, that they will use in their sites. No problem to handle that in my end. Just need to give the user the capability to get the code for the newsletter that they can embed at their end